# SSIS:Dts Script task has encountered an exception in user code: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

The package contain script task shows below error

```
Dts Script task has encountered an exception in user code:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation
```

The script task code is

```
public void Main()
        {
            string Str_Filepath = Dts.Variables["User::FilePath"].Value.ToString();

            bool bl_exist=false;


            if (System.IO.File.Exists(Str_Filepath))
            {
                bl_exist = true;


             }
             else
            { bl_exist = false; }

            Dts.Variables["User::V_Exist"].Value = bl_exist;


            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

Comment: What have you checked so far?  Do the data types of your SSIS variables match the data types used in your C# code?  Have you been able to narrow the error down to a particular line?

Comment: yes ssis data type is bool

Comment: Did you add the variable to the read or the write collection?  You can view this from the *Script* tab inside the *Script Task Editor*.

Answer (score 1):

That simply means the code has error.

did you set the V_Exist data type to boolean?